# need dynamic programming solution

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

The [problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/coin-on-the-table) is the following:

Given a matrix of characters. In the very beginning of the game I am at position (0, 0) in the matrix. Depending on the character in the current position (i, j) I can move Up (if the current character is 'U'), Down if the current character is 'D', Right if the current character is 'R' and Left if the current character is 'L'. Once I reach position with character '*' I cannot move any more (there is exactly one such position). I have some time K in which I have to reach the character. I also have right to change characters, s.t. I can reach character ' * ' faster, but for each changing I pay cost of 1. In the end I have to return the min number of changes I have performed s.t. I have to reach character ' * ' in time k. If it is not possible I have to return -1.

My idea is as follows:

1. traverse the whole matrix, to find the position of character ' * '.
2. create boolean method `isReachable(x, y, k)`, which tells me if character at position `(x, y)` is reachable from position `(0, 0)` for time `k`. Here is the method:

   ```
   public static boolean isReachable(int x, int y, int time){
       if(time < 0){
           return false;
       }
       if(x == 0 && y == 0){
           return true;
       }
       if(isInBounds(x-1, y)){
           if(maze[x-1][y] == 'D'){
               return isReachable(x-1, y, time-1);
           }
       }
       if(isInBounds(x, y-1)){
           if(maze[x][y-1] == 'R'){
               return isReachable(x, y-1, time-1);
           }
       }
       if(isInBounds(x+1, y)){
           if(maze[x+1][y] == 'U'){
               return isReachable(x+1, y, time-1);
           }
       }
       if(isInBounds(x, y+1)){
           if(maze[x][y+1] == 'L'){
               return isReachable(x, y+1, time-1);
           }
       }
       return false;
       }

       private static boolean isInBounds(int x, int y) {
       if(x >= 0 && x <= N-1 && y >= 0 && y <= M-1){
           return true;
       }
       return false;
   }
   ```

If the method return true - I output 0 (i.e. there is no need to change any square in the matrix).

If the method return false - I want to perform another method which will tell me the min number of changes. However I dont know how to write it. This is my draft that obiously doesnt work:

```
private static int find(int x, int y, int k) {
    int res = 0;
    if(k < 0){  //my idea is that if the time become < 0 it means that the point is unreachable, i.e. I have to output 0; Howevr this doesnt output 0, just gives 0 to the upper levels of a recursion tree;
        return -1;
    }
    if(x == 0 && y == 0){
        res = 0;
    }
    else{
        int down;
        if(isInBounds(x-1, y) ){
            if(maze[x-1][y] == 'D'){
                down = find(x-1, y, k-1);
            }
            else{
                down = 1 + find(x-1, y, k-1);
            }
        }
        else{
            down = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        int left;
        if(isInBounds(x, y+1) ){
            if(maze[x][y+1] == 'L'){
                left = find(x, y+1, k-1);
            }
            else{
                left = 1 + find(x, y+1, k-1);
            }
        }
        else{
            left = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        int right;
        if(isInBounds(x, y-1) ){
            if(maze[x][y-1] == 'R'){
                right = find(x, y-1, k-1);
            }
            else{
                right = 1 + find(x, y-1, k-1);
            }
        }
        else{
            right = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        int up;
        if(isInBounds(x+1, y) ){
            if(maze[x+1][y] == 'U'){
                up = find(x+1, y, k-1);
            }
            else{
                up = 1 + find(x+1, y, k-1);
            }
        }
        else{
            up = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        res = min(left, right, up, down);
    }
    return res;
}
```

As I wrote in the comments I have two very basic cases which I dont know how to perform:

- when the time < 0 -> it means that the point is unreachable, i.e. I have to output -1 (but I dont know how to do it)
- if I am at point (0, 0) I dont have to do any changes - return 0
- else I check the neighbouring squares for their letters and return what I have from them.

Can someone help me with general idea, because I think mine is wrong. I the problem description it was said that we have to use dynamic programming and recursion

Comment: This seems like a job for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @MarsAtomic Code Review SE is supposed to be for *working* code, so I don't think they'd like this

Answer (score 0):

I haven't solve the problem, but I think my solution is right.
create dp[i][j][dir][step], means the cost in pos(i,j), the direction is dir and need 'step' steps to the position '*'.

assume '*' in I,J, so we need to  calculate dp[I][J][0|1|2|3][0]. 
tot time is states*move, which is (50*50*4*1000)*(4*4). It is enough to solve the problem.